# does docusaurus have an official docker container?

Tags: docusaurus

https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/docker kinda gives the impression that Docusaurus has a Dockerfile in it's main repo but I'm not seeing it in the github repo:

https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/tree/master

I see third party Docusaurus Docker containers on dockerhub (eg. https://hub.docker.com/r/sanjose/docusaurus/dockerfile) but not an official one.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you able to run v2 on docker ?

Comment: try this: https://hub.docker.com/r/awesometic/docusaurus

Answer (score 1):

As far as I read the [documentation](https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/installation), this file is copied to its place on installing Docusaurus. Have you tried running the installation?

Comment: Yep a dockerfile is generated when you run init. This is only in v1 though. We haven't done that/no plans to do that in v2.